# How i do this Scroll trick using Jquery CSS HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i want to scroll a `Div` Synchronizing on `Browser` Scroll Bar, to make the `Div` on the top of `Browser` Scroll Bar When it scrolls. the Attached image will explain more , while the `Div` is the black box[image]

i tried something like this but didn't gave me the required

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #box{
            background-color: red;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 5px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                $("#box").css("top",$(this).scrollTop()+"px");
            });
        });
    </script>
  <div id="box">
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 1000px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing this (if it's even possible).  You have no way of knowing the "top" of the scrollbar.  It changes with window height, and from browser to browser.  You can make it move up and down with the page though, something like this...

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 1000px;"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $("#box").css("top", $(this).scrollTop() * 1.2);
    });
});
```

That's not *exactly* what you display in your image, but it's close.  There are too many variables to do exactly what you want, and most of them are not available to Javascript.

**[working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/FypVc/1/)**